# Mostrar solamente cuando se escribe en el campo de texto

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap-4

En el tutorial de Bootstrap 4 de W3 hay una apartado que se llama B4 Filters, es como un buscador con JS, y busca las palabras que se encuentran en un DIV con un campo de texto. Pero quiero que el DIV esté oculto y se muestre solo cuando yo escriba en el campo de texto. Aquí el código:

```
<div class="container mt-3">
<h2>Filter Anything</h2>
<p>Type something in the input field to search for a specific text inside 
the div element with id="myDIV":</p>
<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div id="myDIV" class="mt-3">
<p>I am a paragraph.</p>
<div>I am a div element inside div.</div>
<button class="btn">I am a button</button>
<button class="btn btn-info">Another button</button>
<p>Another paragraph.</p>
</div>
</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
 $("#myDIV *").filter(function() {
  $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con algo como esto.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myDIV").hide();
        $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#myDIV *").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                $("#myDIV").show();
                if (value=="") {
                    $("#myDIV").hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

No se si es la solución mas optima pero funciona, con:

> $("#myDIV").hide();

ocultamos el div desde el principio, y cada vez que el usuario introduzca algo el div para a ser visible con:

> $("#myDIV").show();

Mientras el campo no este vacio el div siempre sera visible.